# Verify tab with Javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps, dom-events

In my website using Wordpress I have a tab plugin (WP-UI Tabs,Accordions, Sliders), and since in two tabs I have Google maps embedded code, I need to use a Javascript function (not jQuery since my plugin won't allow it) to force resize of the second map so that the center of the map doesn't go to the left top corner.

So, is there away with JavaScript to make an if to verify if I am in the a specific tab call the resize map?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
});
</script>
```

I need an `if` before the trigger but i'm not sure what to put there.

Here is the tab code:

```
[wptabs type="accordion" mode="horizontal"]

[wptabtitle] Map 1[/wptabtitle] [wptabcontent]
```

Here is the Google maps code embed:

```
[/wptabcontent]

[wptabtitle] Map 2[/wptabtitle] [wptabcontent]
```

Here is the Google maps 2 code embed.

```
[cf]js[/cf] //this is to call the js function


[/wptabcontent]

[/wptabs]
```

Updated Code:

Firefox shows me this:

```
 <div id="wp-accordion-1" class="wp-accordion wpui-light wpui-styles"></p>
<p><h3 class="wp-tab-title"> Place A</h3> <div class="wp-tab-content"><div class="wp-tab-content-wrapper"></p>
<p>Coordenadas GPS:<br />
Latitude: Norte<br />
Longitude: Oeste</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><iframe src="http://maps.google.pt/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=pt-BR&amp;geocode=&amp;q=42.654471,-2.914153&amp;aq=&amp;sll=41.236676,-8.332331&amp;sspn=0.593802,1.234589&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=40.654471,-7.914153&amp;spn=0.018721,0.038581&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;output=embed" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="auto"></iframe><br />
<small><a style="color: #0000ff; text-align: left;" href="http://maps.google.pt/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=pt-BR&amp;geocode=&amp;q=40.654471,-7.914153&amp;aq=&amp;sll=41.236676,-8.332331&amp;sspn=0.593802,1.234589&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=40.654471,-7.914153&amp;spn=0.018721,0.038581&amp;t=m&amp;z=14" target="_blank">Large Map</a></small></p>
<p></div></div><!-- end div.wp-tab-content --></p>
<p><h3 class="wp-tab-title"> Place B</h3> <div class="wp-tab-content"><div class="wp-tab-content-wrapper"></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><script type="text/javascript">
 document.write("yoooo!");
google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
 document.write("yoooo!");

});
</script></p>
<p>Coordenadas GPS:<br />
Latitude: Norte<br />
Longitude: Oeste</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><iframe src="http://maps.google.pt/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=pt-BR&amp;geocode=&amp;q=35.541329,-7.730044&amp;aq=&amp;sll=40.654483,-7.914145&amp;sspn=0.00936,0.01929&amp;g=40.654483,-7.914145&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=40.741339,-7.730044&amp;spn=0.018696,0.038581&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;output=embed" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="auto"></iframe><br />
<small><a style="color: #0000ff; text-align: left;" href="http://maps.google.pt/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=pt-BR&amp;geocode=&amp;q=40.741339,-7.730044&amp;aq=&amp;sll=40.654483,-7.914145&amp;sspn=0.00936,0.01929&amp;g=40.654483,-7.914145&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=40.741339,-7.730044&amp;spn=0.018696,0.038581&amp;t=m&amp;z=14" target="_blank">Large Map</a></small><br />
</div></div><!-- end div.wp-tab-content --></p>
<p></div><!-- end div.wp-tabs -->
```

Comment: Ignore the WP code and post the javascript/HTML/CSS that the browser sees. With WP code 3 experts may be able to answer your question. If you post Javascript there are thousands who can answer.

Comment: But you see, i just want to force resize to center the hidden map. Because with two maps hidden in tabs one of them lost the center point to left corner.
So what should i do?

Comment: Perhaps you can change the URL of the IFrame to set a new center and reload it. Without the API you don't have much control.

Comment: Can you give me an example? I'm not understanding very well what you are suggesting :/